# How did someone log-in to my Gmail account from Kenya?

Tags: google, multi-factor, incident-analysis

While on holiday in France in May I received an email from Google "New sign-in".

> Your Google Account was just used to sign in:
>
> **Nairobi, Kenya**. Tuesday, 26 May 2015 22:10 (East Africa Time).

I hastily changed my password. I've never been to Kenya.

My question is: How did this happen? I believe I practised good security:

1. My password was long—four words similar to `smoke daily us sitting` (I chose this password in 2014, upgrading from something similar to `m0zzarella`).
2. I never used this password for anything else.
3. I used two-factor authentication to receive codes by SMS (no smartphone, so no authenticator app).
4. I created an app-specific password for my phone's email app (Nokia [S40](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_40) phone).

Why didn't two-factor authentication stop the hacker? Here's what I did on holiday:

1. Checked my email
2. Used a web browser on my phone to log in to a Google website.

I can't remember which web browser I used. I had both Nokia Xpress (default browser) and Opera Mini. (Since then a software upgrade replaced the default browser with a version of Opera Mini). I know both of these work by 'sending the data via their servers'.

Is it possible a password or SMS was intercepted? All this happened while I was on holiday and using a foreign phone network. Has this happened to anyone else?

---

It's a shame Google didn't prevent the sign-in. Previously on another account Google contacted me "Suspicious sign-in prevented" when someone tried to log in from China.

Comment: Is it possible you were phished? 2FA is not necessarily immune to phishing.

Comment: It is important to check which IP address you have. Several factors have to be considered. Which dynamic IP is assigned. Whether a proxy is used, this can be conscious or unconscious. Therefore, I check my IP fairly regularly on [ip-info.org](https://ip-info.org/?language=en) If I use TOR for example, then I see with [ip-info.org](https://ip-info.org/?language=en), whether or not TOR really works.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Your password was not stolen. As you pointed out, Opera Mini uses proxy servers. Per [the link](http://forums.opera.com/discussion/1864116/google-account-sign-in-location/p1) provided in [thexacre's answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/104340/10885), Google incorrectly identifies the servers as being in Nairobi, Kenya:

> When you use Opera Mini, you're connected to Opera servers, which
>   download websites you want, compress and transform them, and at the
>   end they are sent to your phone. So the idea is similar to proxy
>   servers. IP address on the screenshot you attached is in fact one of
>   Opera Mini servers, so you shouldn't be worried. I don't know why it's
>   detected as Kenya, you'd better ask Google.

So everything was fine except for Google's IP geolocation.

Comment: Tested Opera Mini. IP is `141.0.12.164`. Google reports it Nairobi, Kenya. http://en.utrace.de/ip-address/141.0.12.164 reports it as Opera Mini servers, Norway http://en.utrace.de/whois/141.0.12.164

Comment: It is very unlikely it would give you the same IP if you're in a different country and it might not give you the same IP if you are.

Comment: Read that thread. I there are proxy servers in several places in the US and Holland mentioned in it. Presumably you get connected to the fastest server based on your location and network.

Comment: There has been some buying and selling of ipv4 addresses as we start to run low.  It seems pretty likely that a place like Kenya might have excess and could sell them to somewhere else that wants them for a nice sum of money.

Comment: The location detection stuff is pretty unreliable.  Ferinstance: YouTube thinks that my solidly USA IP is actually in Canada, so I always end up at "YouTube CA"...

Comment: Why the quotation markup in this answer?

Comment: It's a quote from the link?

Answer (score 45):

Seeing as you're using Opera Mini this is a likely explanation:

> Unlike straightforward web browsers, Opera Mini **fetches all content
>   through a proxy server** and reformats web pages into a format more
>   suitable for small screens.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_Mini

Of course it's difficult to be certain, and 2FA is still vulnerable to certain attack vectors such as phishing.

It seems others have noticed the [same thing](http://forums.opera.com/discussion/1864116/google-account-sign-in-location/p1).

If you have the IP address used I'd probably Google it and also look it up in a [GeoIP database](https://www.maxmind.com/en/geoip-demo) to see if it's assigned to any organisation (eg. Opera).

You might also like to consider creating a new app specific password just to be safe, seeing as app specific passwords are a significant threat if compromised.

Comment: Yup, Opera Mini was the first thing that came to mind when I was reading the OP's question. Opera Mini would be the SSL endpoint if you were browsing an HTTPS website - I have no idea if data transmitted between the phone and Opera Mini's rendering servers is encrypted.

Comment: If anything was sniffed it is likely to be the application specific password that avoids 2FA.  I would regenerate that to be sure.