# How to find full geo location of computer from IP address?

Tags: ip, geolocation

I lost my computer and I need to find it. I know IP address of computer. How to find location of computer from IP address?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I detect real location of the user through their IP address?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/108885/how-can-i-detect-real-location-of-the-user-through-their-ip-address). In short: you can't get the __exact__ location but you might get a rough estimate which still might be totally wrong. How accurate the method it depends on various circumstances but don't expect it to be more precise than 50 km or so.

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://www.iplocation.net/

Plug in the IP and you are good to go.

Do note there is a difference with public and private IP. 192.168.1.1 will not find you anything

Comment: This website provides little information: only city I want to know the exact location IP address my computer. Is it possible to know this? Hackers can find it but I don't know how.