# How has someone gained access to the password for my Google account?

Tags: passwords

Earlier today, I received an automated text from Google stating..

> Google blocked someone with the password for (email address) from signing in to the account. Learn more: google.com/signins

I immediately changed my password. I checked where in the world the sign in came from, and it said Luang Prabang in Laos. I'm in the UK.

I only use this account so that I can subscribe to a number of users on Youtube, so I really can’t see why it’d be a target. I haven't had to type the password into this account recently (we’re talking months) as my phone remembers the password and stays logged in. I haven’t used this password on any other accounts of mine and would consider myself to practice good cyber security.

Unlike Colonel Panic’s question ([How did someone log-in to my Gmail account from Kenya?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/104338/how-did-someone-log-in-to-my-gmail-account-from-kenya)), this was actually somebody else signing into my account.

My question is, how has a complete stranger managed to get access to the password for my personal account?

Comment: There's no guarantee it _was_ a complete stranger, they could be using a VPN, Tor, or a proxy that exits in Laos.

Comment: Does it mention what type of device/browser was used to attempt logging in?

Comment: @Sonickyle27 there was a computer screen icon so assuming a PC. No other info apart from the IP address!

Comment: you can protect your account using a 2nd factor https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185839?hl=en

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were dozen possibilities for the compromise, Let me say the possible exploitation where hacker might got your password :

**1)You might be reusing the same password again** :

You might be having the password which was reused from any of the breached accounts, Inorder to check whether your account comes under breach you can check under sites like [haveibeenpwned](https://haveibeenpwned.com/).There were sites like databases.today which provide breached database information too.

**2)You might be victim of keylogger or any spy programs** :

You might have copied a song/movie/software to a friend through USB drive and your friend might possibly sent keylogger or copied passwords along with it.

**3)You might be used your gmail in open wifi hotspot** :

This is the worst case of you being targetted , You might be signing in open wifi hotspot where your password might be sniffed.

**4)You might be using weak password/your security question might be very easy to crack**

**5)you might be shoulder-surfed**.

Now let's see what we can do next :

- Never repeat passwords
- Enable two step authentication for your gmail account
- Clear all active sessions in your account
- Check for apps which has authorization and remove it[privacy check of google does it]
- Always have a habit of scanning pendrive before copying using antivirus scanners which is maintained uptodate
- Never use weak passwords and have a  eye over the security questions which you have set
- Never signin at open wifi hotspots.

Comment: Regarding open WiFi: Google in particular uses https, and uses it correctly: your password should only ever be sent encrypted to Google's servers even on open WiFi.